# How to exclude a specific link from a Mailing's statistics

Tags: civimail

I send a newsletter via CiviMail and in it there is a style link to load a Google font.
This link gets many hits in the Mailing report, but has no relevance for me.
Is there a way to exclude this specific link from the Mailing statistics report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know you could use webfonts remotely in emails (or, it hadn't occurred to me). Here are some ways you could approach this - pick one! (Or more.)

### Modify the recorded data

The "visit" records are stored in DB table `civicrm_mailing_event_trackable_url_open` and the URLs themselves are in `civicrm_mailing_trackable_url`. By removing matching entries from `civicrm_mailing_event_trackable_url_open` you'll zero those numbers off the top of your report.

Don't remove the entries in `civicrm_mailing_trackable_url` or the redirects to webfonts will stop working, breaking the font in future views.

### Modify the recorded data (automated)

Once you have the query for the above, you could add a "cleanup" job to remove clicks where the URL matches (say) `/.*(css|woff)$/`. This would mean your reports stay clean - but cleanup jobs are a "code smell" IMO, so it's not a great solution.

### Change the email - embed the font

You could potentially [base64 encode the webfont into the email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/woff-base64-encoded/) (this should increase the number of people seeing it in the correct font). That would remove the remote request entirely, but it won't work for an email that has flown!

### Change the email - don't use a font

It's an option ... obviously you went to some effort to put a font in, but I'll include this for completeness :)

### Exclude `.(woff|css)` URLs from your reports

You could add an extension which excludes these types of URLs from display in the reports. This feels like a bad approach (you still end up tracking those URLs, slowing down the email, and filling your DB with data you don't need - but then hide the data from your report). But it's possible and might be less work than getting a fix into core, so again ... for completeness.

### Modify CiviCRM - only track clickable URLs

It seems like CiviCRM is tracking any URL pattern, which suggests civicrm looked for something like `/['"]https?://(.*)['"]/` - but could perhaps only be looking for *links*. You could gather some data on this to file a feature request.

- Does CiviCRM add link tracking to all URLs in emails, or just some?
- Does CiviCRM add link tracking to `<link href="style.css" rel="http://example.org/style.css">` but not `<style type="text/css">@import http://example.org/style.css</style>`? (Maybe it's the href= that confuses Civi?)
- ... ask lots of questions, propose an improvement, consider other use cases, help make it happen!